# Why does Rubymine say this is invalid ruby code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, markdown, rubymine

I am new to ruby and rails and am working on my README.md for my first commit. I have this subheader:

````
###Configuration

Rails defaults to using SQLite for the database. If you would prefer to use another database driver you will need to edit config/database to point to your database. Here is an example configuration for PostgreSQL:
```ruby
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: myapp
  password: password1
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: ookmakyi_dev

test:
  <<: *default
  database: ookmakyi_test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: ookmakyi
```
````

However I noticed RubyMine isn’t highlighting my code and when I check it is giving me these errors related to my database example:

> Expected: ; or end of line :32

> Unexpected: a& :32

> Expected: ; or end of line :33

> Expected: ; or end of line :34

> Expected: ; or end of line :35

> Unexpected: < :35

> Expected: string end :50

Is it correct?

Comment: Since I copy and pasted the lines and there was text above it the lines related to the errors are a bit off. Here are the correct lines:
`Expected: ; or end of line :1`, `Unexpected: a& :1`, `Expected: ; or end of line :2`, `Expected: ; or end of line :3`, `Expected: ; or end of line :4`, `Unexpected: < :4`, `Expected: string end :50`

Comment: On a side note this is not really something you need to document in your README. Its pretty basic rails stuff thats covered by the guides.

Comment: You've specified that it's Ruby code (with ```ruby), while it appears to be yml. Did you make it on purpose? With ```yml there're no complaints from the IDE's side.